# How to fix the depends libcurl3?

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux, mongodb

When I install Mongodb,it says that depends mongodb-org-server,so i install that.
But after that,it says i need to fix the dependence libcurl3,but my system has install libcurl4,it couldn't search the libcurl3.
My system is kali 4.19 debian 4.19 and i add the source is debian9.

Comment: What are your sources.list[.d] contents? Does *"and i add the source is debian9"* mean that you're trying to add a new (non-kali) source?

Comment: In the mongodb install guide,it need you to add a source in the /etc/apt/source.list.d/mongodb.list,

Comment: Is that source 100% compatible with your Kali? From the broken packages it sounds like it's not.

Comment: I don't know what version of debian that my kali linux.But kali is belong to the debian series,so i choose the debian9,if you have any idea,please tell me .

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB server are you trying to install? It sounds like you may be trying to install a MongoDB package which is for an older version of Debian. In Debian 9 the `libcurl.so4` library is provided by `libcurl4`; in older versions this library was provided by `libcurl3`. Since these packages both provide the same library they will conflict. You need to install packages that consistently depend on `libcurl4`. Try following: [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Debian](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/#install-mongodb-community-edition).

Comment: But the offical install guide haven't point out the other operation,I don't know where to find the method..

Comment: Same problem on Ubuntu 18.01 (Bionic, LTS)

Answer (score -1):

Another way to solve libraries dependencies issues is to use a docker container.

For example in that case, once docker-ce installed, you could run something like this :

```
docker run -d --name mongo-4.0.9  -p 127.0.0.1:27017:27017  --restart unless-stopped -v /var/lib/mongodb:/data/db mongo:4.0.9
```

In that way, you do not depend on your system dependencies.

Hope this helps.